# Nginx is forwarding to apache2, but the user get url with :3000

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

After setting apache2 to listen on port 3000 and server php files(wordpress) hitting blog.mysite.com:3000 loads my wordpress install no problem. Then I set up nginx listening on port 80 as a proxy to apache. This is working fine, my only issue is that when users hit blog.mysite.com, its get redirected to blog.mysite.com:3000 instead and this is not the desired behavior. Looked online for a few solutions involving adding some php code to my wp-config.php but didnt worked. Any help with this?

**EDIT:**

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  appsrd.devmbs.com;
        root /home/ubuntu/projecs/APPS-RD;
        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /home/ubuntu/projects/APPS-RD;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_buffers 12 12k;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect  http://appsrd.devmbs.com:3000   http://appsrd.devmbs.com;

        }
}
```

**EDIT:**

/wp-admin is being displayed but the root of the site, is ging in a redirected loop.

127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2012:12:29:25 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 301 529 "http://appsrd.devmbs.com/wp-admin/options-general.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1"

This request is getting fired like 12 to 15 times.

**EDIT:**

Weirdest thing, I deleted the database and went into http://www.mysite.com, and the redirect loop was gone, I got a msg that wordpress couldn't find a DB which was supposed to happens. Then I created a new database, ran the wordpress install and the same arises. The admin works fine but the site page gets redirect loop.

Comment: Have you checked that the Site Address/Wordpress Address in the general settings is correct? I'm guessing it should not include the :3000

Comment: Lol, this seems to be the issue, in the wordpress Setting the site address had :3000 in the url, I remove it, but now only the wp-admin works. The site is not showing up.

Comment: Can you post your ngninx config? What do you see in the access logs?

Comment: Added nginx.conf, which access logs should be looking into nginx access logs or apache access logs?

Comment: Checked the access, if I hit the site, the logs is showing like 10 access in a row then i get this message on the browser This webpage has a redirect loop.

Comment: I would check the nginx error log too. I'm not an nginx expert, but you looked at http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress?

Comment: Since the title of this question no longer represents my current issue  I will close this question and add another. If you like you can answer I will accept your answer since your help was beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that in the wordpress setting I had wrong Address so it was adding :3000 at the end of the url. Since the title of this question no longer represent my current issue I will close it and create a new question.